# DataGrid лишняя колонка слева

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Проблема с DataGrid. Появляется лишняя колонка слева.

XAML

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit" 
        x:Class="Ragnar_ControlPanel.MainWindow"
        Title="RAGNAR - Control Panel" Height="367" Width="512" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Icon="favicon.ico" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
    <Grid>
        <GroupBox Header="Управление" Margin="227,26,10,10">
            <StackPanel>
                <Button x:Name="DeleteAllFilesAndFoldersButton" Content="Удалить все файлы" Margin="10,96,132,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White" Click="DeleteButtonClick"/>
                <Button x:Name="Test" Content="Test" Margin="10,96,132,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White" Click="TestBtn"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>

        <Menu Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="Компьютеры">
                <MenuItem Header="Выход" Click="Exit"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="О программе" Width="90" Click="About"/>
        </Menu>

        <DataGrid Name="DataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10,26,0,11" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Background="{x:Null}" IsHitTestVisible="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Компьютер"  Width="100" Binding="{Binding DG_ComputerName, Mode = OneWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="IP" Width="100" Binding="{Binding DG_IP, Mode = OneWay}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Вот скрин:

[image]

Comment: так а где лишняя колонка? судя по коду, у вас д.б. две колонки, они видны. проблема в скролле? или в чем?

Comment: Слева между рамкой и колонкой "Компьютер" зазор, если увеличить изображение четко вырисовываются строки на этом зазоре.

Comment: ок, понял. а не в Margin ли дело? вы проверяли?

Comment: В общем что-то с привязкой (ObservableCollection), буду разбираться.

Comment: @z668: Странно. Попробуйте посмотреть при помощи [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), относится ли зазор к `DataGrid` или чему-то ещё.

Comment: Да да, зазор относится к коллекции как я понял использовав Snoop. Вот скриншот: http://i5.5cm.ru/i/S6ea.png Право, не понимаю откуда эта колонка берется в коллекции, вот описание коллекции: http://hashcode.ru/questions/331626/c-observablecollection-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA-datagrid-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: Благодарю, помогло. Запостите как ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте у DataGrid выставить свойство `HeadersVisibility="Column"`